# How to create layout similar to the image provided in the link in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to Android development. I want to create layout similar to the image i have provided below in the link.

Layout image that i want to create in my android application, click on below link to view.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nv2TH.gif

This is the layout i wrote which is not yet meeting the standard in the image provided.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/anim"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/musicTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Music Title"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/musicArtistName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/musicTitle"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Singer Name - Artist Here"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

how do i create this type of xml layout.I want to know how to implement this? Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following the idea is to make a layout with weight sum and give each child part of the weight

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/banner_broken_image"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/musicTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Music Title"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/musicArtistName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/musicTitle"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Singer Name - Artist Here"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@android:color/black"/>

    </>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you design a layout in Android you need to understand the view you have to use.

In the image that you have linked, from top to down, there are:

- ImageView, with others TextView over this
- Custom view, you need to implement your own or search a library, this represents the sound
- LinearLayout (horizontal) with 3 Buttons(Imagebutton), the controls of the player
- ProgressBar with 2 TextView at the start and the end, the progress of the song
- Bottom Navigation bar

Hope this analysis helps you now and next time you see a layout!